# Unresolved reference for widgets

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GMbxX.png)I create a plain text and text view but when I write their id in main activity they appear as an unresolved reference in spite of I import android.widget.TextView and EditText. Could you please help me about it ?

Thanks for all interest.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7WSXN.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cant access an element like that.

Use something like this in ikinciAktivite.kt

```
      val text=  findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textView2).text
```

In main activity

```
      val text=  view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textView2).text
```

Comment: I have a button that will change the activity and send the data I inputed to the other activity when I clicked on.

Comment: I added the pictures of the codes on my post

Comment: I have changed my answer please check.

Comment: Thank you so much this solved my problem :)

Comment: but I didnt understand that it was working like that just writing widget's id in the education video Im getting but didnt work in my editor :/

Comment: Maybe in your education video, they were using binding. Pleaseeeeee provide the link or any info of your education video to check. Meanwhile, If my answer solved your issue. Please accept it.

Comment: I'm sorry that I cannot provide any link or info about the video because it is both in turkish and publishing in a website which only turkish people can register and use. Yes your answer solved my issue thank you again.